# String operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get only 'ABCD' from string  'ABCD150117T15' in java script.

I would like strip rest of the string from 'ABCD' in this example and generally everything until but excluding the first number character.

thanks

Comment: Don't understand what exactly you wanted to do...you could achieve it by using `.substring` function on string.

Comment: I would like to get only word before numeric number starts.

Comment: Go ahead and add that to your question. "Match text before numbers start"

Comment: Edited and answered accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
'ABCD150117T15'.match(/^\D+/)[0]
```

This would give you everything until the first number then :)

Comment: I doubt the string is always ABCD, but who knows

Comment: Actually I may get sometimes ABCD150117T15/A150117T15. It's not a hard coded value. I am looking for word/letter before number starts in the string

Comment: adjusted  it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use regex then to match the first digit, and then subtring it to the text;

```
var str = 'ABCD150117T15';
var index = str.search(/\d/);
var text = str.substr(0,index);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `index` and not `index+1`? (I'm not familiar with str.search)

Comment: EDITED : My bad, I totally forgot string.seach return an 0_started index like substr

Answer (score 1):

You can match for a-z

```
'ABCD150117T15'.match(/^[a-z]+/i)
```

you can match anything that is not a number

```
'ABCD150117T15'.match(/^[^\d]+/)
```